# python encode error appears when there is Chinese in the string

Tags: python, unicode, decode, chinese-locale

Below code throw encode error:

```
import os

path = u"E:\\project\\robot_framework\\第一个测试项目\\logs\\log-20170330-094807.html"

os.system("scp "+path+" root@192.168.0.160:/root/jenkins/workspace/RobotFramework/logs/")
```

error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "E:\project\robot_framework\PythonDemo\src\try.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.system("scp "+path+" root@192.168.0.160:/root/jenkins/workspace/RobotFramework/logs/")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 31-37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: [This post might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294213/how-to-decode-unicode-in-a-chinese-text), it seems like you need to encode and decode it first.

Comment: @PikeD. I've tried encode() decode() unicode(), but no help

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) the string

```
import os

path = u"E:\\project\\robot_framework\\第一个测试项目\\logs\\log-20170330-094807.html".encode("utf-8")
os.system("scp "+path+" root@192.168.0.160:/root/jenkins/workspace/RobotFramework/logs/")
```

Another way:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

The above code maybe solve some encoding problems, but the use of `sys.setdefaultencoding()` is discouraged,

See more details from [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: E:/绗竴涓祴璇曢」鐩甛logs/log-20170330-094807.html: No such process

Comment: @AlexBruce I simplified the path, you should change it to `E:\\project\\robot_framework\\第一个测试项目\\logs\\log-20170330-094807.html`