# How to change the coding for python array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I use the following code to scrape a table from a Chinese website. It works fine. But it seems that the contents I stored in the list are not shown properly.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

x = requests.get('http://www.sohu.com/a/79780904_126549')
bs = BeautifulSoup(x.text,'lxml')

clg_list = []

for tr in bs.find_all('tr'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    for i in range(len(tds)):
       clg_list.append(tds[i].text)
       print(tds[i].text)
```

When I print the text, it shows Chinese characters. But when I print out the list, it's showing \u4e00\u671f\uff0834\u6240\uff09'. I am not sure if I should change the encoding or something else is wrong.

Comment: Use `unicode` to store the values in variables

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma Can you write a simple line of code for that?

Comment: Please use Google and do it yourself.

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma I tried this.         clg_list.append(str(tds[i].text.encode('utf-8')))
It didn't work. Not sure why.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294213/how-to-decode-unicode-in-a-chinese-text

Comment: After some search, I think using Python 3 solved the problem and it's the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in this case.

When you print a python list, python calls `repr` on each of the list's elements.  In python2, the `repr` of a unicode string shows the unicode code points for the characters that make up the string.

```
>>> c = clg_list[0]
>>> c # Ask the interpreter to display the repr of c
u'\u201c985\u201d\u5de5\u7a0b\u5927\u5b66\u540d\u5355\uff08\u622a\u6b62\u52302011\u5e743\u670831\u65e5\uff09'
```

However, if you `print` the string, python encodes the unicode string with a text encoding (for example, utf-8) and your computer displays the characters that match the encoding.

```
>>> print c
“985”工程大学名单（截止到2011年3月31日）
```

Note that in python3 printing the list will show the chinese characters as you expect, because of python3's better unicode handling.