# list with special characters

Tags: python, xml, list, encoding, python-2.x

Using Python 2, I am saving strings from a variable (which is out of an xml tag) and am storing it into a list.

First: the strings contain special character, when I print them they don't correctly show up even that am using encode("ISO-8859-1")

Second: The strings show up each one in a list and I want them to be in the same list

```
import lxml.objectify
from lxml import etree
import codecs
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
file_path = "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Morphalou-2.0.xml"
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(file_path, events=("start", "end")):
    if elem.tag == 'orthography' and event =='start':
        data = elem.text
        my_list = []
        if data is not None :
            for i in data.split('\n'):
                my_list.append(i.encode("ISO-8859-1"))
            print (my_list)
```

This is what Am getting

```
['abiotique']
['abiotiques']
[u'abi\xe9tac\xe9e']
[u'abi\xe9tac\xe9e']
[u'abi\xe9tac\xe9es']
[u'abi\xe9tin']
[u'abi\xe9tin']
[u'abi\xe9tins']
[u'abi\xe9tine']
[u'abi\xe9tines']
```

This is what am expecting:

```
['abiotique','abiotiques','abiétacée',...]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882550/5320906

Comment: One file: Morphalou-2.0.xml

Comment: It's a shame that you're forced to use Python 2, the Unicode handling in Python 3 is a lot saner. In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 handles this automatically, you don't need to use `encode`.
As for the list, you're creating a new one with each iteration, create it above the loop, and print it after iterating over the XML elements has finished.

Working example (I've added the word `abiétacée` to an XML a bunch of times to reproduce your situation):

```
my_list = []
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(file_path, events=("start", "end")):
    if elem.tag == 'orthography' and event =='start':
        data = elem.text
        if data is not None :
            for i in data.split('\n'):
                my_list.append(i)
print (my_list)
```

outputs

> ['abiétacée', 'abiétacée', 'abiétacée', 'abiétacée']

Comment: Thanks @Artier, fixed it.  As for Python2.7, I'll try going over the docs to find something helpful