# Why python2 print unicode behavior change in different situation?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

We define a dict which contains two unicode value

```
d={'k1': u'中文', 'k2': u'English'}
```

Then print the dict. The Chinese value will be printed in below behavior

```
print(d)
{'k2': u'English', 'k1': u'\u4e2d\u6587'}
```

But when print just the value, it will behave in different way

```
print(d['k1'])
中文
```

Then convert it to json and print. The behavior different again

```
print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
{
  "k2": "English", 
  "k1": "\u4e2d\u6587"
}
```

So why the behavior change

Comment: You do realise that Python 2 is supposed to be dead, yes? :-) You should be using Python 3 as much is at all possible.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882550/5320906